# Is there a way i can use GCP Storage as external drive?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-10, google-cloud-storage

I'm a hobby photographer and take load of raw photos. I was wondering if there is a possibility to get rid of my external drive and use GCP Cloud Storage instead. I would require to access, read, write files directly from Adobe LightRoom.

Can I have a drive displayed on My PC in windows 10, just like I can see C:,D: i'd like to see gs: drive there.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You will need a third party product such as Cloudberry Drive.

Comment: You can mount a Unix volume with GCS fuse, but it's not compliant with windows. Could be possible if you had had a Mac for example. Third party product is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use GCP's storage service as a network drive, That's what Cloud filestore does.

This is not Google Cloud storage, But this can be another option.

You can mount Cloud Filestore persistent disk to your windows 10 filesystem.

This allows you to use GCP persistent disk as usual like C:,D: drives.

But it is liitle bit expensive, So you need to compare with other options.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=db1a71c7-a731-4709-bc9d-7db425eaa8b8) is GCP price calculator.

Comment: Filestore doesn't have public IP. If you want to achieve this, you need to create a VPN between your local computer and the GCP VPC where is plugged the Filestore instance. Not sure that is the expected answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [GcsFuse-Win](https://github.com/weswu8/gcsfuse-win) version which is backed by [Google Cloud Storage Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage). This is the first gcs fuse on Windows allows you to mount the buckets/folders in the storage account as a the local folder/driver on Windows system. To install the service on the Windows you must need a GCP account. I suggest you to read out the limitations before deploy in the production.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this, and think the answer may lie with Microsoft Azure File Share, which will allow you to map a file share to your local computer without a VPN.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows